# How to configure single Bot to multiple Slack accounts?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have developed a Bot using Microsoft Bot Framework and configured it to one of my slack account.

Can I use the same Bot to another slack account? If yes how can I configure it from Microsoft Bot Framework dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In the Microsoft Bot Framework dashboard, click on the Add to Slack button that appears in the Slack Channel row and follow the flow to authorize the bot into the new Slack team.

[image: Add to Slack button]

Comment: [sateesh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5635374/sateesh) did my answer helped you?